# how to disable dnsmasq service in CentOS 8

Tags: linux

I am install kubernetes v1.18 in CentOS 8, but the coredns start failed, tell me the port 53 is in using, and I using this command to find which app using the port:

```
lsof -i:53
```

then I found `dnsmasq` service are using this port, how to disable or close the auto start the dnsmasq service in CentOS 8? I am trying to kill the process but next time it still started, then using this command but not works:

```
systemctl disable dnsmasq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides `systemctl disable dnsmasq`,

```
sudo sed -i 's/^dns=dnsmasq/#&/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

then restart the networking services

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
```

after that kill `dnsmasq`

```
sudo killall dnsmasq
```

Comment: Hi, in CentOS 8, dnsmasq config is not exist in NetworkManager.conf, how to disable it?